# Multiple Connections in Yii in a single query?

Tags: php, database, yii, connection

I need to copy a table in a database to another database both in same server in Yii. So for that i can use a single query to get all values but the query need to execute two databases. 
In Yii. I have db and db2 in my config file

so,

```
 $connection1 = Yii::app()->db1;

 $connection2 = Yii::app()->db2;

 $sql = "insert into test ()values()"; // Need two database table access ??

 $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);  //How can i execute using both connections??

 $row = $command->execute();
```

Please help..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If user in any DB connection have access to both tables you can transfer data just in one query. You need no second connection or query. You need just to use name of second database and use database.table names.

Comment: We can do this using plain php in a single query. I need to know is there an easy way doing that using Yii framework??

Comment: Wait, why did you thought that single query is not usable in Yii? You are still can use the Yii to get a database and table names, use createCommand to make an sql query. So what you need? Did you want to transfer data between databases using Yii DAO?